# jQuery TimeSlider refreshing cells

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this timeslider component:
https://github.com/v-v-vishnevskiy/timeslider

Demo:
http://v-v-vishnevskiy.github.io/timeslider/demo/demo.html

I am trying to change the start_timestamp of this slider:

```
<div id="c1" class="timecell" start_timestamp="1468231842698" stop_timestamp="1468239761464" style="left:503.0011225231481px;width:167.63221081018517px;background-color:#76C4FF;">2:11:58</div>
```

By using

```
$('#c1').attr('start_timestamp', '14682310000');
```

But the problem is that the slider won't update until I move it by dragging.

Anyone have an idea on how to update the slider same time as I update the attribute?

Comment: have you tried like this: `$('#c1').TimeSlider({start_timestamp: 14682310000});`

Comment: Didn't work.
That TimeSlider({start_timestamp}); sets the time where ruler starts, the cell's start time is at `.TimeSlider({ init_cells: [ {'_id': 'c1', 'start': xxxxx })` I think

Comment: So you want to change the `start_timestamp` of a cell and not the one of your slider? Did you try to reinitialize your cell? `$('#yourSlider').TimeSlider({ init_cells: [ {'_id': 'c1', 'start': 14682310000})`

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking to do, but your example did not work.

Comment: iam searching for the same solution

Answer (score 0):

You can add/edit a cell by doing: `$("#slider123").TimeSlider("edit", cell);`

Also adding, toggling, editing, removing, removing all cells and shifting the where the time slider starts.

Using "add", "toggle", "edit", "remove", "remove_all" and "new_start_timestamp" respectively. Most take a cell but remove just takes a cell id.
Example to add new:

```
$("#slider123").TimeSlider("add",{'_id': 'c3', 'start': 60*12*1000, 'stop': 60*20*1000*2});
```